# Loading files from directory from user

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, directory, uploading

I'm trying to load a lot of files from a directory. I used to be able to do it by having this

```
#directory where all data will be stored
dataDir="C:/Users/me/Desktop/Data/"
Files=[] #list of files
for file in os.listdir(dataDir):
    Files.append(scipy.io.loadmat(dataDir+file))
```

But now, I'm trying to have the user select the folder so I have this:

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import *

root=tkinter.Tk()
filename=filedialog.askdirectory(parent=root,title='Choose a file')
print (filename)


#directory where all data will be stored
dataDir=('%s',filename)
Files=[] #list of files
for file in os.listdir(dataDir):
    Files.append(scipy.io.loadmat(dataDir+file))
```

and it is giving me this error:
"for file in os.listdir(dataDir):
TypeError: listdir: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or None, not tuple)

I tried making filename into a string by doing str(filename), and it still wouldn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: "filename" is already a string. You only need to add the path separator. I recommend you let python do that: `Files.append(scipy.io.loadmat(os.path.join(filename, file)))`.

Comment: `('%s', filename)` is a tuple. Perhaps you meant `"%s" % filename`? Though, I don't understand why you don't just do `dataDir=filename`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create tuple in command

```
dataDir=('%s',filename)
```

and you use it in `listdir(dataDir)` which expect string

Use `filename` directly in `listdir`

```
 for file in os.listdir(filename):
```

Comment: I did that and just used filename instead of dataDir for all instances, but now 
I get [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C:/Users/me/Desktop/Data/'

Comment: this is not Python problem but your system problem. You don't have permission to access this folder or you run script as different user which don't have access to your folder

Answer (score 0):

When you define `dataDir = ('%s', filename)` you are creating a tuple with two elements. One is `'%s'` and the other the value of `filename`.

If I understand correctly you shoud use `dataDir = '%s' % filename`. That way `dataDir` will be a string with the value of `filename`.

Answer (score 0):

The error states that the path you give `listdir` should be a `str` and that you gave it a `tuple`.

With `dataDir=('%s',filename)`, `dataDir` is a tuple containing two strings. However, filename is already a `str`. Instead of `os.listdir(dataDir)`, try `os.listdir(filename)`.

You will need to `import os`.